# Change link to permalink inside post content

Tags: posts, permalinks

I have a post content and in that content I have couple of internal links Now inserting those links via editor I put the id instead of slug name.

Is there any way so that when it displays in the site it automatically detects the id and change to permalink.

Or I need to copy the permalink and put it in the post?

Comment: How many of these do you have?

Comment: I have couple of links.

Comment: Then do it manually. Automating this is not worth the time for a couple of links.

Comment: Just wondering what if we have 20 links.

Comment: Still manually.

Comment: hmm..have you encountered such issue yet

Comment: Not specifically, but I know what it would take to write the code. It isn't worth it until you get to 30, 40, maybe 50 and up.